# AspectJ pointcut for a parameter type

Tags: java, generics, annotations, aspectj

I have this kind of method

```
public List<@TestAnnotation Payload> foo() {
   //...
}
```

I would like to create a pointcut in order to update each Payload which would be returned by foo().

I have tested the following but it does not work (the method foo() is not intercepted):

```
@Around("execution(java.util.List<@com.ote.TestAnnotation *> * (..)))")
public Object execute(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
   //...
   return point.proceed();
}
```

Comment: My first approach would be checking around parenthesis `@Around("execution(java.util.List<@com.ote.TestAnnotation *> * (..)))")` . If your **execute** method not working and if it doesn't throw an exception, there is a problem in your package/method definition.

Comment: Thanks fiskra. But when I told "it does not work", I would like to tell the method foo() is not intercepted byt the advice, although it follows the good pattern. Sorry for the mistake.